# What is the best practice for using a shared background view across multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, window

Often in my apps, I need to use a background image or custom view with a gradient like so:

[image]

Right now I'm just defining a `BackgroundView` class that renders itself however I need for that project, then I make the root view of each view controller an instance of that class. It's a decent solution, but there are some use cases in which it is not sufficient. For example, if I want to make a controller fade out like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transitionDurationOut, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 0
        }) { (Finished) in
        }
```

The screen will fade to black (the default color of the window). I'd rather make it so that that I can fade a controller's view out to reveal the background instead. I could accomplish this with a container view, but I wish to cut out as much boilerplate code as possible. Is there instead some way to give the window a root view of some kind that will appear behind the active controller if its view becomes transparent?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a pretty good solution by setting the subclass as the view controllers root view. What about adding a clear subview to the view controllers root view and performing the fade on that subview instead of the root view.

Example:

```
self.view = BackGroundView() // Gradient background

let fadeView = UIView()
fadeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

/* Add content to fadeView here */

self.view.addSubview(fadeView)

UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transitionDurationOut, animations: {
        self.view.fadeView = 0
    }) { (Finished) in
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using a container view, but I don't want to junk up my view hierarchy. It's a workable solution though, so have an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will add a view to the window directly:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Let's add a background view to the window so that controllers can fade out without the screen turning black.
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        let bgFrame = window?.frame ?? CGRect(0,0,0,0)
        let bgView = BackgroundView(frame: bgFrame)
        window?.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)

        return true
    }
```

Not really sure if there are performance implications or some reason not to do this. I also don't think this will resize the view if the device rotates. Looking for input.

Answer (score 0):

If the major issue boils down to *fading to the background view*, an easy solution would be to *fade in a view with that same background on top of your `view`hierarchy*.

```
let coverView = UIView() // With custom background
coverView.alpha = 0.0
self.view.addSubview(coverView)
UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transitionDurationOut, animations: {
    coverView.alpha = 1.0
})
```

That way, for the fading part, you don't have to move around `subviews`, deal with to much transparency or change the overall structure of your app.